# Cannot pass price into Stripe Checkout nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, db2, e-commerce, payment

I am using the embedded nodejs / javascript code for stripe checkout on my ecommerce website. However, I am trying to pass the name of the product(s) the customer will add to their cart, and the price as well, so I can display the items and prices on Stripe Checkout page.

I ran into the issue after making a connection to DB2, I cannot get the price of each item to be passed into the stripe checkout session. I think it may have to do with async, but even if it is, im not sure how to fix. I am also receiving the error: "(node:45673)UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid integer: NaN"

(excuse the messy code. also some variables are not in use, just ignore)

```
  app.post('/create-checkout-session', (req, res) => {

    var amount = stringify(req.body)
    console.log(req.body.sessionID)
    var userId = req.body.sessionID
    console.log("email: " + req.body.customer_email)
     var email = req.body.customer_email;
    var deliveryTotal = req.body.totalWithDelivery;
    var totalVal = amount.split("=");
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(totalVal[1]);
    //console.log("TOTAL PRICE: " + totalPrice);
    var finalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100);

    var finalTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100) + parseFloat(Math.round(deliveryTotal));
    console.log("final total: " + finalTotal);
    var itemName = ""
    var itemPrice = ""
    var totalNewPriceTest = ""
    //query to database
    
    var productsStripe = "select * from " + userId
    console.log(userId)
    console.log("query to db for displaying cart on stripe page")
    ibmdb.open("DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID="";PWD="";", function (err,conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(productsStripe, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log(rows)
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                 itemName = rows[i]['ITEM']
                 itemPrice = rows[i]['PRICE']
                 totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(rows[i]['PRICE'])
                console.log("item name : " + itemName + " " + itemPrice )
                totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest);
                console.log("final overall prcie: " + (totalNewPriceTest))
            }
            console.log("inside productsStripe function.")
            console.log("overall prcie: " + totalNewPriceTest)

      })
   })

   totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest)
  

   var grandTotal = totalNewPriceTest;
   var finalGrandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal)
   console.log(parseFloat(finalGrandTotal))



   
    //stripe
    const session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ['CA'],
          },
          
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: 'CAD',
              product_data: {
                name: itemName,
              },
              unit_amount: finalGrandTotal,
              //finalTotal * 100
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'localhost:1001/successPg',
        cancel_url: 'localhost:1001/catalogue',
        customer_email: email,
      });
      console.log(session)
      res.json({ id: session.id });
      //console.log("customer id" + customer.id)
      console.log("totalNewPriceTest " + totalNewPriceTest)
});
```

can anyone help? thank you in advance, and sorry for the terribly written code :(

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, it's a classic concurrency issue, first of all, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) complete guide from MDN explains asynchronous javascript very well.

To briefly answer your case, you will need to continue executing stripe code in the query block. Why? Because you need to **wait** for the DB connection to open followed by a query execution, which both are asynchronous.

When you bypass those blocks, you're basically telling javascript to execute code in parallel, which in your case not what you want, you want to wait for the query to finish.

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', (req, res) => {

  var amount = stringify(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.sessionID)
  var userId = req.body.sessionID
  console.log("email: " + req.body.customer_email)
  var email = req.body.customer_email;
  var deliveryTotal = req.body.totalWithDelivery;
  var totalVal = amount.split("=");
  var totalPrice = parseFloat(totalVal[1]);
  //console.log("TOTAL PRICE: " + totalPrice);
  var finalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100);

  var finalTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100) + parseFloat(Math.round(deliveryTotal));
  console.log("final total: " + finalTotal);
  var itemName = ""
  var itemPrice = ""
  var totalNewPriceTest = ""
  //query to database

  var productsStripe = "select * from " + userId
  console.log(userId)
  console.log("query to db for displaying cart on stripe page")
  ibmdb.open("DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID="";PWD="";", function (err,conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(productsStripe, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(rows)
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        itemName = rows[i]['ITEM']
        itemPrice = rows[i]['PRICE']
        totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(rows[i]['PRICE'])
        console.log("item name : " + itemName + " " + itemPrice )
        totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest);
        console.log("final overall prcie: " + (totalNewPriceTest))
      }
      console.log("inside productsStripe function.")
      console.log("overall prcie: " + totalNewPriceTest)

      totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest)


      var grandTotal = totalNewPriceTest;
      var finalGrandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal)
      console.log(parseFloat(finalGrandTotal))



      // continue executing here    
      //stripe
      stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ['CA'],
        },
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: 'CAD',
              product_data: {
                name: itemName,
              },
              unit_amount: finalGrandTotal,
              //finalTotal * 100
            },
           quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'localhost:1001/successPg',
        cancel_url: 'localhost:1001/catalogue',
        customer_email: email,
      }).then((session) => {
        console.log(session)
        res.json({ id: session.id });
        //console.log("customer id" + customer.id)
        console.log("totalNewPriceTest " + totalNewPriceTest)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('stripe err: ', err);
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Other useful tips to follow:

- Don't write business logic inside the router, instead create a controller file and move the logic into it.
- Instead of connecting to the DB upon every request, create a DB connection instance and keep it open and available whenever you need it, start with creating its own helper file and then export the connection.

Comment: thank  for the response! I did follow what you said, no errors, however it still doesn't reach the stripe checkout page... it logs in the console: Promise { <pending> }. i did research this and it says this has to once again do with async. not sure how to fix, read something about .then may work as well?

Comment: looks like `sessions.create` returns a promise, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to write following lines inside query callback :-

```
totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest)
var grandTotal = totalNewPriceTest;
var finalGrandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal)
console.log(parseFloat(finalGrandTotal))
```

And for error check before parsing the data to int or float like

```
if(!isNAN(field))
   value = parseFloat(field);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did follow what you said, no errors, however it still doesn't reach the stripe checkout page... it logs in the console: Promise {  }. i did research this and it says this has to once again do with async. not sure how to fix, read something about .then may work as well?